# How to display select query results using ajax in a form in drupal7

Tags: ajax

Please give me some solution for this. I want to display the Database select query results in a form using ajax in drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifics it's tricky to answer your question but here's a very basic example:

```
function MYMODULE_some_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['select'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Option',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(1,2,3)),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'some-form-results-wrapper',
      'callback' => 'MYMODULE_some_form_ajax'
    )
  );

  $form['results'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="some-form-results-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
  );

  // If the form has been submitted, build up your results and display them
  if (isset($form_state['values']['select'])) {
    $rows = db_select('some_table', 't')
      ->fields('t')
      ->condition('some_field', $form_state['values']['select'])
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();

    $header = array();

    $form['results']['#markup'] = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
  }
  else {
    $form['results']['#markup'] = '<p>The results will appear here when you change the dropdown option.</p>';
  }

  return $form;
}

function MYMODULE_some_form_ajax($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['results'];
}
```

You might want to check out the `ajax_example` module included as part of the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), it has a lot of code and comments that will help you understand what every piece of the above example does.